# Returning a value from a sql select after a try catch

Tags: java, sql, string, jsp

I want this method to return ap string after reading from the table, but it seems like it returns only the initial value I gave it, any thoughts?

```
public String ReadAp(String val) {

    SQLHelper sql = new SQLHelper();
    String apStr = "Test ap initial";
   try
       {
           sql.Init("DB_Name");

           ResultSet rsData = sql.RunSelect("select AP from DB_Name.myTable where     

MD='"+val+"'");

           apStr = rsData.getString("AP");

       }
   catch(Exception exInit)
       {

           System.out.println("Excepted while attempting to connet to: ");
       }



return apStr;

}
```

Comment: Read this carefully: [xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Exception ......................

Comment: @jlordo. That one is awesome. haha :)

Comment: @RohitJain: Didn't know little bobby tables?

Comment: @jlordo. Nope. What's that?

Comment: @RohitJain: It's the kid of the mom you see in the comic ;)

Comment: @jlordo. Hahaha :) Now going through some more comic. :)

Comment: @RohitJain: A few more classics: [292](http://xkcd.com/292/), [1171](http://xkcd.com/1171/), [1168](http://xkcd.com/1168/) and [927](http://xkcd.com/927/). Don't forget to read the tooltips.

Comment: @RohitJain http://xkcd.com/1171/ , this one is super funny, got 99 problems, jay-z style ;)

Comment: @jlordo. Loved 1168, and 1171. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get a ResultSet Object in jdbc you are always supposed to do

```
if (rs.next()) {
   // rs.getString(...
}
```

that is because the query can return no values therefore the need to check if there is a next row, and if you don't do next() each time (even for the first one) you will get nothing.

Comment: I did this, the problem is that the String is not returned at the end of the method.

Comment: According to the code you showed, you didn't call rsData.next(), before calling rsData.getString. And that is needed for the ResultSet to return a value IF there is a value in the database for that record

Comment: First of all, the program you executed throws an exception ? Can you show the code for SQLHelper ?

Comment: It was a problem in getting the IP address to connect to the Database.